# Java Script get data from server (asp.net) and save it in local storage (client side)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm getting a json object from server-side. but i haven't been able to save it in LocalStorage! 
this is how it looks in FireBug: **If you cant see the pictures clearly try opening them in a separate page** ( right click and click on open on new tab)

Thanks in Advance !
[image: Response Tab"]

[image: Json Tab]

this is how i'm getting the data using Ajax but it's not writing anything in local storage

```
$.ajax(
       {
           type: "POST",
           url: "Default.aspx/loadGantt",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           //data: "{taskId:" +taskId+ "}",
           data: "{}",
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

           success: function (response) {
               //console.debug(response);
                   var prj = response.d;
                   validatResult(prj)
                   if (localStorage) {
                       localStorage.setObject("teamworkGantDemo", prj);
                   } else {
                       $("#ta").val(JSON.stringify(prj));
                   }
                   //prj = response;
                   //validateResult(prj);

                   if (typeof (callback) == "function") {
                       callback(response);
                   }
                else {
                   jsonErrorHandling(response);
               }
           }
       });

</script>
```

the result suppose to look like this when i save the data in localstorage (HTML5) but it's not happening: 
[image: LocalStrage]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to throw in an object into `localStorage` Change

```
 localStorage.setObject("teamworkGantDemo", prj);
```

to

```
 localStorage.setItem("teamworkGantDemo", JSON.stringify(prj));
```

or simply

```
localStorage["teamworkGantDemo"] =  JSON.stringify(prj)
```

But if you are insistent on using a wrapper around this, you could do this :

```
Storage.prototype.setObject = function(key, value) {
    this.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
}

Storage.prototype.getObject = function(key) {
   return JSON.parse(this.getItem(key));
}
```

Then use it this way :

```
 localStorage.setObject("teamworkGantDemo", prj);
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked well but i needed to remove `validatResult(prj)` as well.